# discord.py my mute command blocks other commands

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I'm making a timed mute command for my Discord server but when I use .mute command, the bot doesn't respond for a while, then it works. But while the member is muted, other commands are not working and when mute time ends, the commands that i wrote in the mute time are working. Here is the command:

```
@commands.command()
    async def mute(self, ctx, member: discord.Member, time1, reason):
        time1 = int(time1) * 60
        guild = ctx.guild
        var1 = 0
        for role in guild.roles:
            if role.name == "Muted":
                var2 = var1
                continue
            else:
                var1 += 1
        for channel in guild.channels:
            await channel.set_permissions(guild.roles[var2], send_messages=False)
        for rol in guild.roles:
            if rol.name == "Muted":
                await member.add_roles(rol)
                await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} muted by {ctx.author.mention}, reason : {reason}")
                time.sleep(time1)
                await member.remove_roles(rol)
                await ctx.send(f"{member.mention} can type now.")
```

And when member is unmuted automatically, "on_ready" event works again with no reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nothing else in your code will run when someone is mutted because you use `time.sleep`. Using `time.sleep` will freeze your entire code.
To solve your problem, you can use the [`asyncio`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html) library, especially, [`asyncio.sleep`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#sleeping).